Efficient Algorithms for Resource Allocation with Asymmetric Constraints
Resource allocation problems frequently appear in operations research, where the goal is to allocate resources optimally under various constraints. While many classic formulations assume symmetric constraints, real-world scenarios often involve asymmetry. For instance, consider a cost function $C\left ( x \right )$ where $C\left ( x \right )\neq C\left ( -x \right )$, or capacity constraints $a_{ij}\neq a_{ji}$ between nodes in a network.
A simplified example:
We aim to minimize
$$\min\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{i, j}c_{ij}x_{ij}$$
subject to Knapsack-type constraints for resources:
$$\sum\limits_{j}x_{ij}\leq u_{i}\;\forall i, \sum\limits_{i}x_{ij}\leq v_{j}\;\forall j$$
where $c_{ij}$ represents asymmetric costs ($c_{ij}\neq c_{ji}$), and $u_{i}, v_{j}$ are heterogeneous capacities.
Additional details:

$x_{ij}$ represents the amount of resource allocated from node $i$ to node $j$. The values can be continuous or binary, depending on the context.
The constraints are primarily of the knapsack type, though other constraints (e.g., bounds on the total flow or specific exclusion constraints) might also apply.
While $i\neq j$ typically holds, self-loops ($i= j$) may exist in specific scenarios with distinct $u_{i}, v_{i}$.
LP or MIP solvers could potentially address this problem, but scalability and solution efficiency are major concerns for larger instances.

I’m looking for insights on:

Efficient algorithms or heuristics for solving resource allocation problems with such asymmetry.
Techniques to handle or preprocess the problem, e.g., transforming asymmetric constraints into a more tractable form.
Any references to real-world applications or similar problem structures.


Welcome to OR.SE. Could you elaborate more on the problem details? For example,


What does $x_{i,j}$ actually mean?


Are the knapsack constraints the only ones in the model?


Is $i \neq j$ in each combination? (If not, how about $v_{i}, v_{j}, u_{i}, u_{j}$?)


Why not try to use an LP/MIP solver to deal with the problem?



If your variables are continuous and any additional constraints are linear, you have a linear program. Contemporary solvers can handle LPs quite efficiently.
